# add indexing to database using codeigniter migration?

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

How can i add index to any field in database using codeigniter migration.?
I have tried with alter query but i didn't find array key for indexing to pass in alter query?

```
$fields = array('photo_id' => 
                 array('type' => 'INT',
                       'constraint'=>11,
                       'after'=>'photo_req_id',`enter code here`
                       'null'=>false));
```

And i also try to find on codeigniter documentation but not mention anything about indexing.
Guys please help to set indexing by using codeigniter migration method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexing is done by using the `add_key` function [documented here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html#adding-keys).

To create a PRIMARY KEY index on `photo_id`

```
$this->dbforge->add_key('photo_id', TRUE);
```

To create a secondary index on `photo_id`

```
$this->dbforge->add_key('photo_id');
```

Comment: But it will add as primary key not adding indexing to that key.

Comment: Yes, it does. Please examine the source code in DB_forge.php

Comment: I checked but in that also mentioned that  add_key is used for primary key  not for indexing.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the code comment which is about the `if` statement that checks if `$primary` is TRUE. Dig deeper and examine how `$this->keys` is used later in `$this->_process_indexes()`.

Comment: To create a key with multiple columns, you can pass an array as an argument like this. `$this->forge->addKey(['columns1', 'columns2']);`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such interface until CI 3 and the under development CI 4.
You can use

```
$this->db->query('CREATE INDEX your_index_name ON your_table_name (your_column_name);');
```